# SQL Server CE does not give error when there is no free space on the disk

Tags: database, sql-server-ce

I use SQL Server CE (Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91) in a web service. The problem is the SQL Server CE driver does not return error on `ExecuteNonQuery` if there is no more space on hard drive where the database is located.

Test environment & steps of test:

1. the database for the test is located on a drive E: (flash-disk)
2. there is 80kb free on the disk - the database size is 64KB
3. I call insert into a temp table several times (see code below) and there is no problem - the data is inserted. When enough amount or rows are inserted, the SQL Server CE allocates another 64KB
4. now there is 16kb free on the disk, the database size is 128KB
5. I call insert into a temp table several times (see code below) and after number of successful inserts - no more rows are inserted anymore and there is no error

The database is 128KB and there is no more space on drive E: for next page to be allocated. But `mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns 1 (this must be the number of inserted rows) and there is no error. The code looks like as this:

```
string connString = "Data Source=E:\temp\logs\testDB.sdf;Persist Security Info=False; max database size=4090; max buffer size=4096; default lock timeout=3000; autoshrink threshold=100; Case Sensitive=true;";

using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString)) 
{
    string sql = "insert into temp (status, step, dt, data) values (1,'Register','2015-12-21 16:43:59',0,0,'Test Data')";

    SqlCeCommand mycommand = conn.CreateCommand();
    mycommand.CommandText = sql;

    int result = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); //always 1

    conn.Close()
}
```

What I tested also is Event handler method:

```
public static void MessageEventHandler(object sender, SqlCeInfoMessageEventArgs e) {
   foreach (SqlError error in e.Errors){
        Console.WriteLine("problem with sql: " + error);
        throw new Exception("problem with sql: " + error);
    }
}
```

and before opening of the connection

```
conn.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler( MessageEventHandler );
```

But MessageEventHandler is never attached.

Is there way an error to be thrown or my code to understand the operation `ExecuteNonQuery` is failed (I do not want to do additional check for free space on the disk, etc.) - just error or result to be 0?